# Update with single-character wildcard not working

Tags: sql-server, replace

Why doesn't this work? Is it a character set issue or something? This is driving me crazy. I've been searching all over. Maybe it's just one of those days. :(

```sql
select replace('Doe, John B ',' _ ','')
```

Expected Results: "Doe, John"

Actual Results: "Doe, John B "

If this is not possible with `replace`, how else can I achieve this result?

Comment: What is `charset()`? Missing a `)` at the end?

Comment: @njk That was an accident. It's fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For just this variable:

```
select 
rtrim(reverse(substring(reverse(rtrim('Doe, John B ')), charindex(' ', reverse(rtrim('Doe, John B '))), len(rtrim('Doe, John B ')))))
```

For an entire table:

```
select 
rtrim(reverse(substring(reverse(rtrim(columnname)), charindex(' ', reverse(rtrim(columnname))), len(rtrim(columnname)))))
from tablename
where columnname like '% _ '
```

Comment: I fail to see what the point of all the reverses is. Care to enlighten me? :P

Comment: To get the last index of a space character in the string (after trimming the trailing spaces).

Comment: Basically, trim the trailing spaces, then reverse it to get the first (last when it's forwards) instance of a space, do a substring from there, and then put it back in the correct order.

Comment: Ugh!! All this flipping around is making me dizzy. I don't even know how you managed to write something like that without throwing up, lol. But it WORKS!! Amazing, and yet ridiculous that MS makes use jump through these ridiculous hoops just to do such a simple thing. Well thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

The `REPLACE` function doesn't accept patterns/wildcards in sql server.

Comment: How then can I achieve my goal if `replace` cannot do it? Thanks. :)

Comment: It's also odd that you say that it doesn't accept patterns because the very definition by [Microsoft in the API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx) has "patterns" as the parameters for the function.

Comment: Yes, the name of the parameter is "string pattern". When you read the description of the parameter, it says "Is the substring to be found".